# How to compare 2 arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

This is the first array:

```
$possible_combinations = array(
    1 => array(1),
    2 => array(2),
    3 => array(3),
    4 => array(4),

    5 => array(1, 2),
    6 => array(1, 3),
    7 => array(1, 4),       

    8 => array(2, 3),
    9 => array(2, 4),       

    10 => array(3, 4),

    11 => array(2, 3, 4),
    12 => array(1, 3, 4),
    13 => array(1, 2, 4),
    14 => array(1, 2, 3),

    15 => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
);
```

This is the second array:

```
$seeking = array(2, 3, 4);
```

As you can see `$possible_combinations[11]` matches `$seeking`.

The value of $seeking in this case is 2, 3, 4 but it may be different at other times. How can I run a check against the
$possible_combinations array to see if the $seeking array matches any of the values of that associative array. 
It should return the key of the match if there is one.

Comment: Are you looking for the first occurrence or all possible matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's built-in `array_search()` function for this.

```
$search = array_search($seeking,$possible_combinations);

if ($search !== FALSE) {
    echo 'Found at ' . $search;
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: This is incorrect. What happens if `$seeking` is found at index 0? It should instead read: `if ($search !== FALSE)`

Comment: There was no index 0 in his example, but fixed anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Just gotta protect the people who drive by and copy/paste in the future :)

Comment: `array_search()` will return the first match if found.

Answer (score 2):

> *"any of the values of that associative array"*

You don't have any associative arrays in your question. `$possible_combinations` is a *multi-dimensional* array. Nevertheless, you can use [`in_array`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

`var_dump(in_array(array(2, 3, 4), $possible_combinations)); // true`

If you need to know at what index the needle is found in the haystack, use `array_search` as mentioned by the other answers. Oh, and also note that `array_search` can return zero, so you should verify that it's return value `!== FALSE` when you're checking the result.

Comment: yeah I meant to say multidimensional array not associative. Although isn't it also an associative array since it doesn't start at zero index?

Comment: No, that does not make it an associative array. It's really just semantics anyway as PHP stores associative arrays in the exact same way as numerically indexed arrays. Under the hood they're all the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, use `array_search`:

```
var_dump(array_search($seeking, $possible_combinations, true));
```

It returns the key if found, and `FALSE` otherwise. So make sure to use `===` to compare, i.e.

```
if (false !== ($key = array_search($seeking, $possible_combinations, true))) {
    echo "Found here: $key";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_keys()` Find all possible key matches.
`array_search()` Will return first occurrence.

```
var_dump(array_keys($possible_combinations, $seeking, true));
```

Will match both 0 & 11 assuming

```
$possible_combinations = array(
     0 => array(2, 3, 4),
    ...
    11 => array(2, 3, 4),
);

$seeking = array(2, 3, 4);
```

#### Output:

```
array
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 11
```